# How to know if the PyMedia module is busy

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm making a music player with the PyMedia module and the Tkinter module. I've been Googling for an answer on to to "check" if PyMedia.startPlayback is busy playing a song, but so far I've been unsuccessful. My goal is to be able to play the next song in the queue when the current song stops playing.

for example:

```
def Listen(songs):
        global player
        while True:
            songs+=1
            def play(number):
                player.startPlayback(number)
            def pause():
                 player.pausePlayback()
            #init pymedia player
            player= pymedia.Player()
            player.start()
            play(songs)
            #wait till song is done playing...
            #After finished continue on to the next one
            play(songs)
```

This isn't the exact code but it is the gist of it.
I have python 2.7 on Windows 7. Thanks for you input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://pymedia.org/docs/pymedia.player.html

The docs list an `isPlaying` function for the player. They even use it in the example for the while loop.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the tutorial and not the documentation. I feel foolish now

Comment: @P'sao Haha, it happens. Docs sure do help when they exist! :)

Comment: Apparently they do! Thanks again.